# Output webscraping results to BibTex file

Tags: python, web-scraping

Here is my attempt to output webscraping results to a `bibtex` file.

I would like to use this format as input to the [Zotero](https://www.zotero.org) database.

As [BetterBibtex](https://retorque.re/zotero-better-bibtex/) already has a function to generate customized citation keys, I don't want to reinvent the wheel over here. Therefore, citation keys are generated using the `uuid` hex string just to avoid errors.

Presently, I make use of the [BibtexParser](https://bibtexparser.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html) library to output search results to a dictionary, then feed that dictionary into a database, and use that database to generate a bibtex file, which is the final output.

Just like to know if there is a better and more efficient way of doing this.

## main.py

```
import cnki
import json
from typing import Iterable, Tuple, List
from pathlib import Path

import bibtexparser
from bibtexparser.bwriter import BibTexWriter
from bibtexparser.bibdatabase import BibDatabase

DB_DICT = {
    "cnki": cnki.search,
    "fudan": fudan.search,
    "wuhan": wuhan.search,
    "qinghua": qinghua.search,
    }

def save_articles(articles: Iterable, file_prefix: str, output_format: str) -> None:
    file_path = Path(file_prefix).with_suffix(f'.{output_format}')

    if output_format == "json":

        with file_path.open('w') as file:
            file.write('[\n')
            first = True

            for article in articles:

                if first:
                    first = False
                else:
                    file.write(',\n')
                json.dump(article.as_dict(), file, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)

            file.write('\n]\n')

    elif output_format == "bib":

        db = BibDatabase()

        for article in articles:

            bib_dict = article.as_bib()
            bib_dict = {k: v for k, v in bib_dict.items() if v is not None}  # Remove none values.
            db.entries.append(bib_dict)

        writer = BibTexWriter()

        with file_path.open('w') as bibfile:
            bibfile.write(writer.write(db))


def db_search(keyword: str, *args: Tuple[str]):

    if args:
        
        for db in args:
            yield from DB_DICT[db](keyword)

    else:

        for key in DB_DICT.keys():
            yield from DB_DICT[key](keyword)


def search(keywords: List[str], *args: str):
    for kw in keywords:
        yield from db_search(kw, *args)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    rslt = search(['尹至'],'cnki')
    save_articles(rslt, 'search_result', 'bib')
```

## cnki.py

```py
from contextlib import contextmanager
from dataclasses import dataclass
from datetime import date
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Generator, Iterable, Optional, List, ContextManager, Dict, Tuple
from urllib.parse import unquote
import uuid
from itertools import chain, count
import re
import json
from math import ceil

# pip install proxy.py
import proxy
from proxy.http.exception import HttpRequestRejected
from proxy.http.parser import HttpParser
from proxy.http.proxy import HttpProxyBasePlugin
from selenium.common.exceptions import (
    NoSuchElementException,
    StaleElementReferenceException,
    TimeoutException,
    WebDriverException,
)
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox, FirefoxProfile
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import ProxyType
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver import WebDriver
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement import WebElement
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait


# from urllib3.packages.six import X


@dataclass
class Result:
    title: str  # Mozi's Theory of Human Nature and Politics
    title_link: str  # http://big5.oversea.cnki.net/kns55/detail/detail.aspx?recid=&FileName=ZDXB202006009&DbName=CJFDLAST2021&DbCode=CJFD
    html_link: Optional[str]  # http%3a%2f%2fkns.cnki.net%2fKXReader%2fDetail%3fdbcode%3dCJFD%26filename%3dZDXB202006009
    author: str  # Xie Qiyang
    source: str  # Vocational University News
    source_link: str  # http://big5.oversea.cnki.net/kns55/Navi/ScdbBridge.aspx?DBCode=CJFD&BaseID=ZDXB&UnitCode=&NaviLink=%e8%81%8c%e5%a4%a7%e5%ad%a6%e6%8a%a5
    date: date  # 2020-12-28
    download: str  #
    database: str  # Periodical

    @classmethod
    def from_row(cls, row: WebElement) -> 'Result':
        number, title, author, source, published, database = row.find_elements_by_xpath('td')

        title_links = title.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')

        if len(title_links) > 1:
            # 'http://big5.oversea.cnki.net/kns55/ReadRedirectPage.aspx?flag=html&domain=http%3a%2f%2fkns.cnki.net%2fKXReader%2fDetail%3fdbcode%3dCJFD%26filename%3dZDXB202006009'
            html_link = unquote(
                title_links[1]
                    .get_attribute('href')
                    .split('domain=', 1)[1])
        else:
            html_link = None

        dl_links, sno = number.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
        dl_links = dl_links.get_attribute('href')

        if re.search("javascript:alert.+", dl_links):
            dl_links = None

        published_date = date.fromisoformat(
            published.text.split(maxsplit=1)[0]
        )

        return cls(
            title=title_links[0].text,
            title_link=title_links[0].get_attribute('href'),
            html_link=html_link,
            author=author.text,
            source=source.text,
            source_link=source.get_attribute('href'),
            date=published_date,
            download=dl_links,
            database=database.text,
        )

    def __str__(self):
        return (
            f'題名      {self.title}'
            f'\n作者     {self.author}'
            f'\n來源     {self.source}'
            f'\n發表時間  {self.date}'
            f'\n下載連結　{self.download}'
            f'\n來源數據庫 {self.database}'
        )

    def as_dict(self) -> Dict[str, str]:
        return {
            'author': self.author,
            'title': self.title,
            'publication/university': self.source,
            'date': self.date.isoformat(),
            'download': self.download,
            'url': self.html_link,
            'database': self.database,
        }

    def as_bib(self) -> Dict[str, str]:
        id = uuid.uuid1()
        if self.database == "期刊" or self.database == "輯刊":
            return {
                'ID': str(id.hex),
                'ENTRYTYPE': 'article',
                'author': self.author,
                'title': self.title,
                'journaltitle': self.source,
                'date': self.date.isoformat(),
                'url': self.html_link,
                # 'file': self.download,
            }
        elif self.database == "博士":
            return {
                'ID': str(id.hex),
                'ENTRYTYPE': 'phdthesis',
                'author': self.author,
                'title': self.title,
                'institution': self.source,
                'date': self.date.isoformat(),
                'url': self.download,
                # 'file': self.download,
            }
        elif self.database == "碩士":
            return {
                'ID': str(id.hex),
                'ENTRYTYPE': 'mastersthesis',
                'author': self.author,
                'title': self.title,
                'institution': self.source,
                'date': self.date.isoformat(),
                'url': self.download,
                # 'file': self.download,
            }

class MainPage:
    def __init__(self, driver: WebDriver):
        self.driver = driver

    def submit_search(self, keyword: str) -> None:
        wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 50)
        search = wait.until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'txt_1_value1'))
        )
        search.send_keys(keyword)
        search.submit()

    def switch_to_frame(self) -> None:
        wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 100)
        wait.until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//iframe[@name="iframeResult"]'))
        )
        self.driver.switch_to.default_content()
        self.driver.switch_to.frame('iframeResult')

        wait.until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//table[@class="GridTableContent"]'))
        )

    def max_content(self) -> None:
        """Maximize the number of items on display in the search results."""
        max_content = self.driver.find_element(
            By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#id_grid_display_num > a:nth-child(3)',
        )
        max_content.click()

    # def get_element_and_stop_page(self, *locator) -> WebElement:
    #     ignored_exceptions = (NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException)
    #     wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30, ignored_exceptions=ignored_exceptions)
    #     elm = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(locator))
    #     self.driver.execute_script("window.stop();")
    #     return elm


class SearchResults:
    def __init__(self, driver: WebDriver):
        self.driver = driver

    def number_of_articles_and_pages(self) -> Tuple[
        int,  # articles
        int,  # pages
        int,  # page size
    ]:
        articles_elem = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('td.TitleLeftCell td')
        n_articles = int(re.search(r"\d+", articles_elem.text)[0])

        page_elem = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('font.numNow')
        per_page = int(page_elem.text)

        n_pages = ceil(n_articles / per_page)

        return n_articles, n_pages

    def get_structured_elements(self) -> Iterable[Result]:
        rows = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath(
            '//table[@class="GridTableContent"]//tr[position() > 1]'
        )

        for row in rows:
            yield Result.from_row(row)

    def get_element_and_stop_page(self, *locator) -> WebElement:
        ignored_exceptions = (NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException)
        wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30, ignored_exceptions=ignored_exceptions)
        elm = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(locator))
        self.driver.execute_script("window.stop();")
        return elm

    def next_page(self) -> None:
        link = self.get_element_and_stop_page(By.LINK_TEXT, "下頁")

        try:
            link.click()
            print("Navigating to Next Page")
        except (TimeoutException, WebDriverException):
            print("Last page reached")


class ContentFilterPlugin(HttpProxyBasePlugin):
    HOST_WHITELIST = {
        b'ocsp.digicert.com',
        b'ocsp.sca1b.amazontrust.com',
        b'big5.oversea.cnki.net',
    }

    def handle_client_request(self, request: HttpParser) -> Optional[HttpParser]:
        host = request.host or request.header(b'Host')
        if host not in self.HOST_WHITELIST:
            raise HttpRequestRejected(403)

        if any(
                suffix in request.path
                for suffix in (
                        b'png', b'ico', b'jpg', b'gif', b'css',
                )
        ):
            raise HttpRequestRejected(403)

        return request

    def before_upstream_connection(self, request):
        return super().before_upstream_connection(request)

    def handle_upstream_chunk(self, chunk):
        return super().handle_upstream_chunk(chunk)

    def on_upstream_connection_close(self):
        pass


@contextmanager
def run_driver() -> ContextManager[WebDriver]:
    prox_type = ProxyType.MANUAL['ff_value']
    prox_host = '127.0.0.1'
    prox_port = 8889

    profile = FirefoxProfile()
    profile.set_preference('network.proxy.type', prox_type)
    profile.set_preference('network.proxy.http', prox_host)
    profile.set_preference('network.proxy.ssl', prox_host)
    profile.set_preference('network.proxy.http_port', prox_port)
    profile.set_preference('network.proxy.ssl_port', prox_port)
    profile.update_preferences()

    plugin = f'{Path(__file__).stem}.{ContentFilterPlugin.__name__}'

    with proxy.start((
            '--hostname', prox_host,
            '--port', str(prox_port),
            '--plugins', plugin,
    )), Firefox(profile) as driver:
        yield driver


def loop_through_results(driver):
    result_page = SearchResults(driver)
    n_articles, n_pages = result_page.number_of_articles_and_pages()

    print(f"{n_articles} found. A maximum of 500 will be retrieved.")

    for page in count(1):

        print(f"Scraping page {page}/{n_pages}")
        print()

        result = result_page.get_structured_elements()
        yield from result

        if page >= n_pages or page >= 10:
            break

        result_page.next_page()
        result_page = SearchResults(driver)


def save_articles(articles: Iterable, file_prefix: str) -> None:
    file_path = Path(file_prefix).with_suffix('.json')

    with file_path.open('w') as file:
        file.write('[\n')
        first = True

        for article in articles:
            if first:
                first = False
            else:
                file.write(',\n')
            json.dump(article.as_dict(), file, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)

        file.write('\n]\n')


def query(keyword, driver) -> None:
    page = MainPage(driver)
    page.submit_search(keyword)
    page.switch_to_frame()
    page.max_content()


def search(keyword):
    with Firefox() as driver:
        driver.get('http://cnki.sris.com.tw/kns55')
        query(keyword, driver)

        print("正在搜尋中國期刊網……")
        print(f"關鍵字：「{keyword}」")

        result = loop_through_results(driver)
        # save_articles(result, 'cnki_search_result.json')

        yield from result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    search('尹至')
```

Comment: This doesn't load? I get `bad gateway` for the website.

Comment: The url has been changed to http://cnki.sris.com.tw/kns55

Comment: Though you can follow the link above, `driver.get('http://cnki.sris.com.tw/kns55')` still doesn't connect...

Comment: `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Failed to decode response from marionette`

Comment: The new url seem to have broken your content filter plugin. So I have to disable it for the code to work...

Comment: The code should be working fine now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The code should be working fine now

It doesn't; the site dies with a 503. Anyway:

- `articles: Iterable` should specify what it's an iterable of
- don't accept a free string for `output_format`; use an `Enum`
- for any reasonable size of data, your iterated `json.dump` should not be necessary and you should be able to combine to a single list and a single `dump` call
- `db_search`, rather than accepting `*args`, would be clearer as `*databases`. Also you only need a single `for` loop if you conditionally overwrite `databases` with `DB_DICT.keys()`.
- `search` should have an `Iterable` typehint.
- You have several unused imports. Any self-respecting IDE will point these out to you so that you can delete them.
- `as_bib` should factor out the common columns - ID, author, title and date - to a common dictionary and conditionally update it.
- `self.database == "期刊" or self.database == "輯刊"` should use a set membership check.
- Unused methods like `get_element_and_stop_page` should be deleted. You should be running source control which will make operations like this safe.
- The return typehint for `number_of_articles_and_pages` is wrong; there should only be two tuple elements.
- Delete all of the proxy stuff if you're not going to use it
- `loop_through_results` should have an `Iterable` return typehint
- The database names 期刊, 輯刊, 博士 and 碩士 should be saved to English-language constants such as `MASTERS`, potentially in an `Enum` if the set of known values is understood.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your error. Did you run the code via `main.py`?